# Redis cache not working on Heroku, no idea what is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, heroku, redis

So I setup Redis to go addon for my rails app hosted on heroku. I paid 5 bucks for the addon so that I have access to memory usage, keys in the cache etc. However, my graphs tell me that my app doesn't add any keys into the cache and the long response times on the website also suggest that my app is not caching where it needs to.

The application is basically a social media website just like facebook. Getting the friends of a user is an expensive task that also required to be called often. So I'd like to cache all the friends of all the users.

So to do that I use the Rails.cache.fetch method. Here is the friends method looks like in my User model -

```
def friends
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{self.id}") do
    force_friends
  end
end

def force_friends
  user_ids = Friend.where(
    '(user_id = :id OR friend_id = :id) AND pending = false',
     id: self.id
  ).pluck(:user_id, :friend_id)
   .flatten
   .uniq
   .reject { |id| id == self.id }

  users = User.where(id: user_ids)
end
```

I believe my Redis to go setup is right since I'm successfully able to run the following in my heroku rails console

```
$ heroku run rails console
>> REDIS.set("answer", 42)
"OK"
>> REDIS.get("answer")
42
```

Which suggests me that I'm probably doing something wrong in my friends method

Comment: Have you configured rails to use a non default cache store?

Comment: I think so. My application.rb has the line config.cache_store = :redis_store, 'redis://localhost:6379/0/cache' and it seems to be working locally

Comment: With Heroku, you need to use the Redis URL provided by the environment.

Comment: @ItamarHaber thanks! that worked!